# On storyboards, views and passing data along

Tags: storyboard, xcode4.2

In my Xcode 4.2 storyboard, i have 2 `UIViewControllers`, `This one time` and `In band camp`

- In `This one time`, i have a `UIButton` with "silly name" on it
- In `In band camp`, i have a `UILabel` with "label" on it

Considering that we're dealing with 2 separate classes **AND** we're in *Xcode 4.2* using `storyboards` (where transition between views is setup via a segue) how can i pass "silly name" from view controller `This one time` to the label in view controller `In band camp`?"

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer but your question is so awesome!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Set the identifier of segue in storyboard to "AwesomeSegue"
2. Implement prepareForSegue method
3. Inside the method, check if identifier of segue matches "AwesomeSegue" - if yes, use the destinationViewControllerObject

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AwesomeSegue"]) {
           InBandCampViewController *ibcVC = [segue destinationViewController];
           ibcVC.yourData = self.someStuff;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had to come up with one tweak for my code and also one alternative when used this solution.

In my case I had a **Navigation Controller** interrupting in the middle. **MainViewController**  **Segue** was pointing to that **Navigation Controller**, then there was another **Segue** from it pointing to **SecondViewController**.

So if you'll ever need to get your **ViewController** from **Navigation Controller**, you could use such code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // ScoreViewController Storyboard Segue
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AwesomeSegue"]) {

        // Finding ViewController that is needed in Navigation Controller
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ScoreViewController *scoreViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Bellow implement your delegate or any data you want to pass
    }
}
```

*Delegate*:
`scoreViewController.delegate = self;`

*Pass data*:
`scoreViewController.newLabel.text = self.oldLabel.text;`

*Call method*:
`[scoreViewController updateLabelText:self.oldLabel.text];`

By the way, passing data you should assign it to the `IBOutlet` from the **Sugue** directly.
If you just pass `NSString` (or anything else), and will try to assign its text to the `UILabel` in `viewDidLoad`, it will be `Nill`.
It is because `viewDidLoad` is implemented before **Segue**.
Using `viewDidAppear` doesn't help here either, as it would load the text after **SecondViewController** is presented to the screen. You might see how `UILabel` text changes from "Label" to "silly name".

Well, if any one has some suggestions, I'm happy to hear, as I'm also just a newbie.