# How to add subview to another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, popover, addsubview

I'm doing an Ipad app. Now I have 2 viewcontrollers, ViewController has a button1 which has a popover segue to the second viewcontroller(PopoverController). Then, the PopoverController has a button2, if I click the button2, I'll receive some UIImage from my server. I want to add fews subviews of UIImageView to the ViewController to display these images if I click the button2.

The button1 works well, the PopoverController can pop up as expected. BUT when I click the button2, nothing happend. I want to know how can I pass the data between 2 viewcontrollers and how to add subviews to another one.

Some codes relating to my problem:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PopoverController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PopoverController *popoverController;

@end
```

PopoverController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface PopoverController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *tempImg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

- (IBAction)addsubviews:(id)sender;

@end
```

I can not just use `[viewController.view addSubview:img1];` in the `- (IBAction)addsubviews:(id)sender;`method to addsubview. So someone can help me? :)

====1st update====

Someone suggest that I have to use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method. I have tried this one by control click the button2 and create a custom segue between button2 and ViewController. When I clicked the button2, it showed :
 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'change'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'`

So I'm wondering whether I should add a `NavigationController`. If so, what should I do?

====2nd update====

I use Paramasivan 's code now, and I found the way to call method from another viewcontroller. The problem now is the newly added subview in my viewcontroller doesn't show up. I guess I have to update my viewcontroller in order to make it visible.

in my `- (IBAction)addsubviews:(id)sender;` method, i invoke the method in ViewController by `[self.viewController createSubViewWithImage:_tempImg];`

so the method can be invoked when i click the button2, but the view of viewcontroller has nothing changed.

Comment: what exactly is your question? "I can not just use [..]" - why?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing when you are using that line?

Comment: @jimpic sorry for that, I mean this line of code could be compiled but did not do what I expected

Comment: @ACB this line of code did nothing, at least I did not see any thing different if I delete this line.

Comment: @Manted, How are you setting viewController property? are you doing, `popovercontroller.viewcontroller = self;` before showing this popover? another way is to pass the image to previous class as `viewcontroller.image = self.tempimage` and then call some method in viewcontroller which will set this image in imageview.

Comment: @ACB I didn't do this. So where should I put `popovercontroller.viewcontroller = self;`? In the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method of ViewController? I'm sorry, I'm new to iOS, so I got a lot of things to learn. :)

Comment: @Manted, Sorry for the delayed reply. Please post the code, where you are showing popovercontroller from viewcontroller. I can give you the answer.

Comment: @ACB that's ok. I use Paramasivan 's code now, and I found the way to call method from another viewcontroller. The problem now is the newly added subview in my viewcontroller doesn't show up. I guess I have to update my viewcontroller in order to make it visible. So could u help me with this?

Comment: @Manted, Even with that, it is the same issue you are facing. In order to do `[viewControllerPassed createSubViewWithImage:imageDownloaded];`, you need to do `popovercontroller.viewcontroller = self;` which you are not doing. The below answers are not at all related to your problem. It is just another way or better approach to do what you are trying to do. Still you need to set the viewcontroller, which I can help if you post the code.

Comment: @ACB yes I add the code `popovercontroller.viewcontroller = self`. so the method can be invoked when i click the button2, but the view of viewcontroller has nothing changed. in my `- (IBAction)addsubviews:(id)sender;` method, i invoke the method in ViewController by `[self.viewController createSubViewWithImage:_tempImg];`.

Comment: @Manted, Where are you adding this line? Before adding try doing `NSLog(@"%@", popovercontroller);` and check if popovercontroller is not nil.

Comment: @ACB i add this in `- (void)viewDidLoad`, oh i forgot to init popovercontroller before this. thanks for pointing this out. now I init them in both of 2 controllers. In viewcontroller's `- (void)viewDidLoad` method, `self.popoverController = [[PopoverController alloc] init];
    self.popoverController.viewController = self;`, in popovercontroller's `- (void)viewDidLoad` method, `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.popoverController = self;`. but still nothing changed to the viewcontroller after i click button2

Comment: @Manted, Let me post an answer. Please check and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `- (void)viewDidLoad`,

```
self.popoverController = [[PopoverController alloc] init]; 
self.popoverController.viewController = self;
```

Make sure that in no other places, you are setting `self.popoverController = ...`.

Do ***NOT*** add anything like `self.viewController = ...` in `popovercontroller` class.  And you dont have to do `self.viewController.popoverController = self;` as well. Just remove these lines if you already have it.

Once these are done, make sure that you are displaying `self.popoverController` only in the popover and you are not creating a new object for `popoverController` class there. So if these are fine, you can use any approach you want for passing the image from `popoverController` class to `viewController` class.

as you mentioned in your comment you can use `[self.viewController createSubViewWithImage:_tempImg];` in your `popovercontroller` class.

**Update:**
If you are doing via storyboard, you need to set this in `prepareForSegue` method and you dont have to create `self.popoverController` at all. Remove that part in your case. You can follow the procedure mentioned here to set up a custom segue and implement `prepareForSegue` method to pass the object. Source: [On storyboards, views and passing data along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855888/on-storyboards-views-and-passing-data-along)

1. Set the name of segue in storyboard to "CustomSegue"
2. Implement `prepareForSegue` method
3. Inside the method, check if name of segue matches "CustomSegue" and then set the `viewController` in the `popoverController` object there as,

Try,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CustomSegue"]) {
        PopoverController *popoverController = [segue destinationViewController];
        popoverController.viewController = self;
    }
}
```

After doing this, you need to call `[self.viewController createSubViewWithImage:_tempImg];` in your `popoverController` class.

Comment: If I removed these lines in my `PopoverController`, I can not call `-(void)createSubViewWithImage:(UIImage *)imageDownloaded` method now.

Comment: @Manted, What is the error? Because if you use that, you are creating new instance of viewController, not the same as previous object. Also how are you showing popover? using code or via story board? The problem is you need to set this to the same object which you are showing as popover. But you are showing a different object for popover.

Comment: I just control click the button1 and drag to PopoverController, and use a popover segue. Is that ok?

Comment: @Manted, In that case you need to do the update section in my answer.

Comment: 1. do i have to create a new segue? or use the `popover segue` from `button1` to `PopoverController`? 2. i have to implement `prepareForSegue` method in `ViewController.m`? or in `PopoverController.m`?   I've tried to control click `button2` and drag to `ViewController` to create a new `custom segue`, which has an identifier of `change` and implement the `prepareForSegue` method in `PopoverController.m`, of course i changed the name inside the method to `change`. But when I click the button2, i got an error: `'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'change'`

Comment: @Manted, Try selecting popover as the type and check. Or else you can just rename the popover segue name to this if that is possible. You have to implement in viewcontroller class if I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Communicating with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) doc, there are several ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController.h add the following

```
-(void)createSubViewWithImage:(UIImage *)imageDownloaded {
    UIImageView *imageViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageDownloaded];
    [self.view addSubView:imageViewTemp];
}
```

In PopoverController.h add the following

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *viewControllerPassed;
```

And after image downloaded, call the following in PopoverController.h

```
[viewControllerPassed createSubViewWithImage:imageDownloaded];
```

Comment: still nothing happend. Is the `viewControllerPassed` here the same thing as my `ViewController` ?

Comment: hi, I can call this method now, but the problem is the newly added subview doesn't show up. Do I need to update viewcontroller to show it? If so, how to implement this? cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data using the below method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewController2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *v2VC = [segue destinationViewController];
        v2VC.yourData = self.someStuff;
    }
 }
```

Comment: so I have to control click button2 to create a new custom segue? I've tried this, then I got the following error: 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'change'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.''